# Symfony, getUser with many relation is too big

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have an entity `User` with many relations. Approximatly 25 `OnetoMany`, `OneToOne` and `ManytoMany.

So, for example, i have an entity `Message`, an entity `Comment` etc... that they even have other relationships.

My problem, when i try to retrieve my `User` with `$this->getUser()` in a controller, i retrieve ALL theses relationships... My object is too big, i can't var_dump for example.

I don't want, when i do `getUser()` retrieve all his messages, comments etc...

Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the association will not be loaded unless you read it.

The problem is you can't use `var_dump()` to debug a doctrine object.

You should use:

```
\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($doctrine_obj);
```

Comment: I don't xant to debug, i want to have a light object, without all his relation

Comment: @ClémentAndraud What the fetch type you defined?

Comment: @ClémentAndraud The fecth mode, if you have not set to `EAGER`, the relations is loaded only when necessary.

Comment: In the annotation ? I have nothing

Comment: @ClémentAndraud So as i said, the relations is not loaded. You could check your sql log, the sql query for the relation will not be fired.

Comment: I have the objet under my eyes ^^ and i see all relations... ;) In my User objet, i have all his messages, comments etc.. and all relations from messages, comments...

Comment: I just have for example : * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Message", mappedBy="user")

Comment: @ClémentAndraud How did you see? By `var_dump`? You can't use `var_dump` to debug a doctrine object, it't will be infinite loop.

Comment: I return my object with a jsonresponse and a serializer.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `fetch` mode on the relationship, for example, using annotations:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Comment", fetch="LAZY")
 */
protected $comments;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AnotherRelation", fetch="EAGER")
 */
protected $anotherRelation;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Example", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
 */
protected $example;
```

Using `EXTRA_LAZY` will just set the field to `null` which I think is what you are looking for. This also works recursively for all your relationships in your tree.

More info: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html